# Calendars - Best Approach to Migrate Exchange Online Public Folders to Nested 365 Groups?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar, public-folders, exchange-online

We have a client who we need to migrate off of Public Folders as those are coming up on EOL.  They have a multitude of calendars, some nested as deep as three levels.  Another calendar they have has ten other calendars under it (not nested).  This way, a member of the primary department calendar has all of the subcalendars appear in their Outlook client (selecting Group A automatically includes Group A1, A2, A3, etc.)  However, from what I've read, 365 Groups do not support nesting (although there is some kind of dynamic-group beta for it that I can't quite wrap my head around), so basically every calendar would be top-level.  I am hoping to avoid that so a department head doesn't have to click 10 different calendars to have them display in their Outlook (don't get me started on the fact that calendar groups in Outlook must be created manually, per-user!).

I was wondering if anyone here had any insight to offer on how they have overcome this situation.  We did look at Calendly as an alternative option, but the client passed on it so we are trying to deduce how to do this natively in 365, with PowerShell or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The feature of nested does exist, but you need to be on Azure.

From
[Nested Microsoft 365 Groups: What You Need to Know](https://petri.com/nested-microsoft-365-groups/) :

> Nested Microsoft 365 groups are a new feature available in preview in
> Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), now part of Microsoft Entra. They
> allow admins to create Azure AD dynamic groups and administrative
> units that can add members from other groups using the ‘memberOf’
> attribute. Apps that previously couldn’t read group-based membership
> in Azure Active Directory can now read the entire membership of these
> new groups.
>
> These dynamic Azure AD security groups can be used for apps as well as
> licensing assignments. The following diagram courtesy of Microsoft
> explains how you can create a dynamic group with members of both
> Security-Group-X and Security-Group-Y, all while preventing members of
> the sub-groups within these two groups to members of a dynamic group.

The article contains many links that can point you to the
information you need, if you intend to use this feature.

Comment: So in order to achieve my goal, would I create the mail-enabled security groups using the method above and then migrate the public folders to those?  Would that retain the calendar hierarchy?

Comment: I can't answer that. I bought this to your attention, but I haven't studied the material myself.

Comment: This will not retain the calendar hierarchy, as mail-enabled security groups do not support nesting by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/compare-groups?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, Microsoft 365 Groups support nesting through [dynamic groups in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-rule-member-of).

More information or guidance, you can refer to these articles:

- [Migrate your public folders to Microsoft 365 Groups in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration-exo/public-folders/migrate-your-public-folders-to-microsoft-365-groups)
- [Best practices for public folder preparation before migrations](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/best-practices-for-public-folder-preparation-before-migrations/ba-p/1909222)